# Partial template specialization constrained by std::derived_from compiles differently by MSVC and GCC

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

```cpp
#include <concepts>

class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

// primary template
template <typename T>
    requires std::derived_from<T, Base>
struct C {
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};

// specialization
template <typename T>
    requires std::derived_from<T, Derived>
struct C<T> {
    static constexpr int value = 2;
};

static_assert(C<Derived>::value == 2);
```

It turns out that MSVC compiles the code just fine ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c6zvb65dP)) while GCC refuses to compile with error message ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ofMqjsr4v)):

> error: partial specialization 'struct C' does not specialize any template arguments and is not more constrained than the primary template

I would like to know which is the correct behavior according to the language standard, and what is the correct way to specialize `C<T>` for all `T` derived from `Derived` (not `Base`) including `Derived` itself in C++20.

Comment: Clang also rejects this. I can't find which part of the standard mandates this, but both GCC and Clang seemingly want you to add `&& std::derived_from<T, Base>` to the specialization's `requires` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC is correct.

`std::derived_from<T, Derived>` does not subsume  `std::derived_from<T, Base>`, so the partial specialization is not more specialized than the primary template, which isn't allowed.

This follows from [[temp.spec.partial.general]/9.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.partial.general#9.2) through [[temp.spec.partial.order]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec.partial.order), [[temp.func.order]/6.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.func.order#6.4), [[temp.constr.order]/1.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.order#1.2) and finally [[temp.constr.atomic]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.atomic#2).

`std::derived_from<T, X>` contains a conjunction of constraints, one of which, chosen for purpose of example, is `std::is_base_of_v<X, T>`.

`std::is_base_of_v` is not a concept, but a variable template. So the primary template has an atomic constraint `std::is_base_of_v<X, Base>` and the specialization one `std::is_base_of_v<X, Derived>`. These two atomic constraints are not equivalent. Therefore in the two constraints on the templates neither is more specialized than the other.

In order to make sure that the constraints on the partial specialization subsume those on the primary one, you need

```
template <typename T>
    requires std::derived_from<T, Base> && std::derived_from<T, Derived>
struct C<T> { //...
```

Now these constraints subsume the ones on the primary template.

---

Also beware that this is not purely a problem with how constraints/concepts are implemented:

`std::derived_from<T, Derived>` and `Derived` being derived from `Base` does *not* imply `std::derived_from<T, Base>`.

`std::derived_from` requires both that the base is unambiguous and that it is accessible. The last part differs from `std::is_base_of`.

Example:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};
struct D : B, C {};

static_assert(std::derived_from<B, A>);
static_assert(std::derived_from<D, B>);
static_assert(!std::derived_from<D, A>);
```

Another one:

```
struct A {};
struct B : private A {};
struct D : B {};

static_assert(std::derived_from<B, A>);
static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, D>);
static_assert(!std::derived_from<D, A>);
```

Comment: I wonder where the standard says that specialization's constraints must subsume the primary template's constraints. This is a language-lawyer question, after all.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://wg21.link/temp.spec.partial.general#9.2

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  interpretation of more specialized is source of ambiguity. If definition of one concept doesn't explicitly rely on another, compiler cannot decide which one is more specialized.

Comment: Haha, having fallen into a trap – seemed as if `std::is_base_of` is not transitive (!) – but now noticing that the template arguments are inverted ;) Seems, though, the other way round would have worked: All `T`s that `Derived` inherits from (general case) is a superset of all those `T`s that `Base` derives from (specialisation). Wouldn't it?